# Dealing with array initialized in and out of functions

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, casting, malloc

I have function which takes and return pointers of pointers (i.e. dynamically allocated, via malloc() 2d arrays, hence: matrices). I have troubles when trying to pass elements being pointed two between pointers whose memory is allocated in and outside functions. I know there must be something very important about pointers here that is eluding me, could you please illuminate me?

```
double** initialize(int N,int M); // ..allocates memory for me and gives me back the "pointer to a matrix".

double** A = initialize(int N,int M);

double** myfun(double** A){

double** P;
P = initialize(int L,int K);

// .. I wanna write element "of" A to the newly allocated memory pointed by P
// .. this crashes

P[l][k] = A[i][j];

// .. this works fine
double temp;
temp = A[i][j];

P[l][k] = temp;

return P;

}
```

EDIT : Here is how initialize works. I do not want to debug the code or build an appropriate matrix here, I would just like to know about the specific behavior of pointers in this instance. The code here is essentialy pseudo-code.

```
    double** A = initialize(int N,int M){ // .. i.e. something along the line of:

 double** A;
      A =  (double**) malloc((N)*sizeof(double*));
      A[0] =  (double*) malloc(area*sizeof(double));
      A[1] = A[0] + 1;
      for (int i=2; i<N; i++) A[i] = A[i-1] + M;

      /* Initialize to zero */
      for (int i=0; i<N; i++) for (int j=0; j<M; j++) A[i][j] = 0;

};
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't make sense. `P = initialize(int L,int K);` is a syntax error. For debugging help post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should not use raw pointers and `malloc` for this purpose in C++ anyway. Use `vector<vector<double>>` , which will allocate memory without making any mistakes.

Comment: Refrain from using arrays.  Put them into a class and call it a matrix.  The matrix class will be easier to pass to functions and allocate in dynamic memory if need be.

Comment: (I agree with comments that you should use an appropriate library type.) Please show your allocation code, your initialization code, and code for an example. (I agree with comments re MCVE.)

Comment: I know perfectly well that this is not the way to do things, I am not interested in making a good matrix class right now. The question is only about the behavior of pointers in this specific instance.

Comment: You want others to tell you what is happening in your code without seeing it. (SInce you don't understand it you are not in a position to judge which part of it they need to see.) It has a bug and you don't want to "debug it" but you want to "know about the specific behavior". That is the *definition* of debugging. Your expectations are contradictory. (Re "I know perfectly well that this is not the way to do things,": Sure, expected that, but just in case, advised.)

Comment: Actually, the code is all there.

Comment: Clearly not, since it doesn't compile, and that's not all you're missing for an MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example usage is consistent with what we would guess the intended usage to be.

In initialize: Presumably the value of `area` is `N * M`. In

```
  A[1] = A[0] + 1;
  for (int i=2; i<N; i++) A[i] = A[i-1] + M;
```

in the first line the `+ 1` should be `+ M`. You should just write

```
for (int i=1; i<N; i++) A[i] = A[i-1] + M;
```

Also you need

```
return A;
```

Since you haven't actually given the code you ran or said what "crash" means, this might not be your (only) problem. For debugging help post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).